# Counting the number of Male & Females from tables

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT 
  student_class.acad_yr,
  (case when((students.gender = 'Male') then count(students.gender) end)) AS Male,
  (case when((students.gender = 'Female') then count(students.gender) end)) AS Female
FROM
  students
  INNER JOIN student_class ON (students.st_id = student_class.st_id)
WHERE
  student_class.acad_yr = '2013/2014' AND 
  left(student_class.class_id, 1) = '1'
GROUP BY
  student_class.acad_yr
ORDER BY
  students.surname,
  students.othername
```

I am getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'then count(students.gender) end)) AS Male,
>     (case when((students.gender = 'Fem' at line 3

Comment: COUNT(CASE WHEN THEN...

Comment: (case when((students.gender = 'Female') then count(students.gender) )end) AS Female.... this is the correct format. Check the bracket before end. Similarly correct the brackets for male portion too....

Comment: The query will execute if you remove ALL your parenthesis that are not needed for `count` or `left`.

Comment: Why you have order by in this query??? What is your logic behind that????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :-

```
SELECT 
  student_class.acad_yr,
  case when students.gender='Male' then count(students.gender) end AS Male,
  case when students.gender='Female' then count(students.gender) end AS Female
FROM
  students
  INNER JOIN student_class ON (students.st_id = student_class.st_id)
WHERE
  student_class.acad_yr = '2013/2014' AND 
  left(student_class.class_id, 1) = '1'
GROUP BY
  student_class.acad_yr
ORDER BY
  students.surname,
  students.othername
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: the answer is good...thank you so much...i just have to apply some changes to it to make it work. thank you guys so much and i appreciate you quick response.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  student_class.acad_yr,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STUDENTS WHERE GENDER = 'Male' AND acad_yr = student_class.acad_yr) AS Male,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STUDENTS WHERE GENDER = 'Female' AND acad_yr = student_class.acad_yr) AS Female,
FROM
  students AS S
INNER JOIN student_class ON (S.st_id = student_class.st_id)
WHERE
  student_class.acad_yr = '2013/2014' AND 
  left(student_class.class_id, 1) = '1'
GROUP BY
  student_class.acad_yr
ORDER BY
  S.surname,
  S.othername
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  student_class.acad_yr,
  sum(case when students.gender = 'Male' then 1 else 0 end) AS Male,
  sum(case when students.gender = 'Female' then 1 else 0 end) AS Female,
FROM
  students
  INNER JOIN student_class ON (students.st_id = student_class.st_id)
WHERE
  student_class.acad_yr = '2013/2014' AND 
  left(student_class.class_id, 1) = '1'
GROUP BY
  student_class.acad_yr
ORDER BY
  student_class.acad_yr
```

I removed the columns you were using in the `ORDER BY`, since it didn't really make much sense.

Comment: the answer is good...thank you so much...i just have to apply some changes to it to make it work. thank you guys so much.